# MongoDB 3.6 - How to modify this aggregate query with $lookup so it can be run on multiple documents?

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregate, lookup

I have 2 collections, I want to do a join on them using the `$lookup` operator. The fields I want to join have different types. I am not allowed to use the `$toObjectId` Operator due to challenges of Upgrading the DB, nor I am allowed to modify the existing data.

### Prescription collection

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("p1"), "currentOrderId" : "o1"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("p2"), "currentOrderId" : "o2"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("p3"), "currentOrderId" : "o3"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("p4"), "currentOrderId" : "o4"} ...
```

### Order Collection

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("o1"), "orderNumber": "123"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("o2"), "orderNumber": "123"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("o3"), "orderNumber": "123"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("o4"), "orderNumber": "123"} ...
```

I have to join the order documents to the prescription documents so my result collection looks something like this :

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("p1"), 
"currentOrderId" : "o1",
"currentOrder": {
       "_id" : ObjectId("o1"),
       "orderNumber": "123"
 }
```

...... ( many more documents) .......

I was able to join only one pair of prescription and order document using the following query :

```
db.prescription.aggregate([
  { $match: {"_id":ObjectId("p1")}},
  { $addFields: { "coid": ObjectId("o1")}},
  { $lookup: {
    from: "order",
    localField: "coid",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "currentOrder"
  }},
  {
    $unwind: "$currentOrder",
  },
])
```

Note I hardcoded the `$match` and `$addfields` to test my query. Now I want to apply this query to be able to join all orders to the prescription collection in batch.

Here is what I think:

1. We have no knowledge of how many prescriptions are there, nor their `_id's`, therefore we need to run one query to get their `_ids`. And store it in a list.
2. I need to apply this query in batch, so I might remove the match operator.
3. I also need to get a list of order `_id's`, I can run another query on the prescription collection in order to get a string list of order ids.
4. I need to somehow convert the string list from step 3 into objectID, in batch.

Sorry, that is all I have right now. I will consider answers involving more queries, as long as the number of queries is constant. Note that I cannot use any operators introduced after version 3.6.

Any bits of help or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `$match` it will runs on multiple document

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr I added $match so I can test my script on a smaller data set. the main problem is my $addFields call, which is currently hard-coded to only add the id of one document. When I remove $match operator, or expand use $in operator along with $match to expand the dataset, is there a way I can modify the $addFields step to perform the query on multiple documents? Thanks